# What religious (or political) differences is Gulliver talking about here?

Tags: gullivers-travels

Near the end of [*Gulliver's Travels*](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/829/829-h/829-h.htm) (part IV, chapter V), the narrator offers a list of differences of opinion that have led to warfare among humans.

> Difference in opinions has cost many millions of lives:  for instance, whether flesh be bread, or bread be flesh; whether the juice of a certain berry be blood or wine; whether whistling be a vice or a virtue; whether it be better to kiss a post, or throw it into the fire; what is the best colour for a coat, whether black, white, red, or gray; and whether it should be long or short, narrow or wide, dirty or clean; with many more.  Neither are any wars so furious and bloody, or of so long a continuance, as those occasioned by difference in opinion, especially if it be in things indifferent.

The absurdity of fighting wars over doctrinal differences is a recurring theme in the novel—the best-known example being the warfare between Lilliput and Blefuscu over which end of an egg to crack open.  In the quote above, Swift is, at least in part, giving silly-sounding descriptions of actual religious controversies.  However, although I do not recognize most of the disagreements he lists.

The first examples, "whether flesh be bread, or bread be flesh; whether the juice of a certain berry be blood or wine," are obviously about the Protestant-Catholic disagreement about [transubstantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transubstantiation).  However, I cannot identify any of the other disputes with certainty (although the reference to "kiss[ing] a post" sounds like it might have something to do with Catholic veneration of crucifixes).  The disputes over coat color and composition sound like they might rather be nationalist differences than sectarian ones; I thought the colors, in particular, might be references to army uniforms, but, if so, it seems quite curious that the famous blue of the French army is not mentioned alongside the English red.

Alternatively, it might simply be that none of the disputes, except the ones about the reality of transubstantiation, were based on actual sociopolitical disagreements than led to warfare.  However, it seems like that would rather diminish the power of the satire.  So are the remaining disagreements that Swift lists identifiable as mocking descriptions of real religious or political issues?

Comment: " I thought the colors, in particular, might be references to army uniforms, but, if so, it seems quite curious that the famous blue of the French army is not mentioned alongside the English red."  When Gulliver's Travels was written, "the famous blue of the French Army" did not yet exist, and most French army uniforms were white..

Comment: "whether it be better to kiss a post, or throw it into the fire" -- yes, the Catholic veneration of crucifixes you mentioned, versus the  [Iconoclasm of many protestant movements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconoclasm#Reformation_era).

Comment: I believe the "whistling" refers to whether music should be permitted in church services

Comment: @M. A. Golding  I believe it is more about different monastic orders than army uniforms

Comment: https://youtu.be/l3fAcxcxoZ8

Answer (score 4):

The references to the coats, in my opinion, might be about various monastic orders, within catholicism. "Dirty" could be a reference to "mendicants orders". Red coats could refer to cardinals.

Though most of the differences would be between protestants and catholics.

Beyond the first clear references to transubtantiation and iconoclasm, the part about "long or short, narrow or wide" may differentiate between the clothes of catholic priests vs protestant ministers.

Globally, I think **everything** is about religion, either catholics vs protestants, or different tendencies within catholicism, or different protestant denominations.

People living in Swift's time were probably able to recognize all those nuances. Possibly even between High Church and Low Church **within** Anglicanism. In our time, only historians of religion would be able to find their way in all these details. I, certainly, am not one.